# python asyncio.open_connection() inconsistent behavior on timeout

Tags: python, asynchronous, tcp, timeout, python-asyncio

I am using python 3.7 with asyncio to create a TCP connection to some hardware on a local network that, like all hardware, might be disconnected or simply turned of.

In case the hardware is disconnected, I noticed that using `asyncio.open_connection()` takes around ~3s to raise an `OSError`:

```
import asyncio
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level='INFO', format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')

async def main(host, port):
    while True:
    try:
        logging.info('trying to connect to %s:%d', host, port)
        r, w = await asyncio.open_connection(host, port)
        logging.info('connected')
        break
    except Exception as error:
        logging.error('error: %r', error)

asyncio.run(main('cryoctrl01', 5000))
```

With output:

```
$ python test.py
2020-05-05 18:31:04,983 trying to connect to cryoctrl01:5000
2020-05-05 18:31:08,039 error: OSError(113, "Connect call failed ('192.168.1.12', 5000)")
2020-05-05 18:31:08,039 trying to connect to cryoctrl01:5000
2020-05-05 18:31:11,111 error: OSError(113, "Connect call failed ('192.168.1.12', 5000)")
2020-05-05 18:31:11,111 trying to connect to cryoctrl01:5000
2020-05-05 18:31:14,183 error: OSError(113, "Connect call failed ('192.168.1.12', 5000)")
...
```

As I know I am on a local network, I wanted to reduce this time so I wrapped the code around an `asyncio.wait_for()` like this:

```
import asyncio
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level='INFO', format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')

async def main(host, port, timeout):
  while True:
      try:
          logging.info('trying to connect to %s:%d', host, port)
          coro = asyncio.open_connection(host, port)
          r, w = await asyncio.wait_for(coro, timeout)
          logging.info('connected')
          break
      except Exception as error:
          logging.error('error: %r', error)

asyncio.run(main('cryoctrl01', 5000, 0.5))
```

But now I have an inconsistent behavior: *sometimes* I get the expected `Timeout` error but from time to time I get an `OSError` instead:

```
$ python test.py
2020-05-05 18:56:18,035 trying to connect to cryoctrl01:5000
2020-05-05 18:56:18,537 error: TimeoutError()
2020-05-05 18:56:18,537 trying to connect to cryoctrl01:5000
2020-05-05 18:56:19,038 error: TimeoutError()
2020-05-05 18:56:19,038 trying to connect to cryoctrl01:5000
2020-05-05 18:56:19,540 error: TimeoutError()
2020-05-05 18:56:19,540 trying to connect to cryoctrl01:5000
2020-05-05 18:56:20,042 error: TimeoutError()
2020-05-05 18:56:20,043 trying to connect to cryoctrl01:5000
2020-05-05 18:56:20,545 error: TimeoutError()
2020-05-05 18:56:20,545 trying to connect to cryoctrl01:5000
2020-05-05 18:56:21,047 error: TimeoutError()
2020-05-05 18:56:21,047 trying to connect to cryoctrl01:5000
2020-05-05 18:56:21,095 error: OSError(113, "Connect call failed ('192.168.1.12', 5000)")
2020-05-05 18:56:21,095 trying to connect to cryoctrl01:5000
2020-05-05 18:56:21,597 error: TimeoutError()
2020-05-05 18:56:21,597 trying to connect to cryoctrl01:5000
2020-05-05 18:56:22,098 error: TimeoutError()
2020-05-05 18:56:22,098 trying to connect to cryoctrl01:5000
2020-05-05 18:56:22,600 error: TimeoutError()
2020-05-05 18:56:22,600 trying to connect to cryoctrl01:5000
2020-05-05 18:56:23,102 error: TimeoutError()
2020-05-05 18:56:23,102 trying to connect to cryoctrl01:5000
2020-05-05 18:56:23,604 error: TimeoutError()
2020-05-05 18:56:23,604 trying to connect to cryoctrl01:5000
2020-05-05 18:56:24,106 error: TimeoutError()
2020-05-05 18:56:24,106 trying to connect to cryoctrl01:5000
2020-05-05 18:56:24,167 error: OSError(113, "Connect call failed ('192.168.1.12', 5000)")
2020-05-05 18:56:24,167 trying to connect to cryoctrl01:5000
2020-05-05 18:56:24,669 error: TimeoutError()
2020-05-05 18:56:24,669 trying to connect to cryoctrl01:5000
```

I noticed that this seems to happen also around every 3s.
Is this behavior coming from the OS?
How should I change my code in order to have a consistent behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You only get `TimeoutErrr` on actual timeouts. If you look at time difference between initiating the connection and the non-timeout errors, you'll see that they occur in less than the 0.5s timeout. Checking for timeout doesn't shield you from *other* network errors, so you can't expect consistency - you simply need to handle both conditions.

If you print the error with `%s` rather than `%r`, you'll see the error message coming from the system. Errno 113 is probably "no route to host", which might indicate a transient network failure on your side. You need to catch `OSError` and decide how to handle them, the typical approach being to retry the connection after an appropriate delay.